# Rx operator for emitting 'n' newest items as a list each time that a source observable emits new event

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Is there an operator ( rxjava operator more specifically ), that would transform the source observable so that it would emit a list of 'n' newest items each time the source observable emits new item.

Something like:

```
---A-----B------C--------D-----------E------->

           bufferNewest(2)

---[A]---[A,B]--[B,C]----[C,D]-------[D,E]--->
```

If there is is not a default operator like this, what is the best way to implement such behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I can't remember if the 2-parameter `buffer(count,skip)` method can do this. If it can't, use `scan()` to do this.

Comment: Bingo! :-) I was going through buffer operators but I apparently didn't understand this one quite right... thanks again